# adding in data.table missing values for each combination of several categories

Tags: r, data.table

I am given a data.table `dt` with some demographic statistics for certain ages and years. Moreover, I have a differentiation into several categories `Cat_1`, `Cat_2` and `Cat_3`

```
set.seed(1)
Cat_1<-c("A","B")
Cat_2 <- c("u","v")
Year_1 <- c(1991:2000)
Age <- c(46:50)
dt1<-CJ(Cat_1,Cat_2,Year_1,Age)
dt1[,Cat_3 := "x"]
dt1[,value:=runif(dim(dt1)[1],0,1)]

Year_2 <- c(1996:2000)
dt2<-CJ(Cat_1,Cat_2,Year_2,Age)
dt2[,Cat_3 := "y"]
dt2[,value:=runif(dim(dt2)[1],0,1)]
dt <- rbind(dt1,dt2)
colnames(dt) <- c("Cat_1","Cat_2","Year","Age","Cat_3","value")
```

For some values of `Cat_3` (here it is the value y), I don't have data for all years (here only starting from 1996 instead of 1991).
I would like now to add for each combination of `Cat_1`, `Cat_2`, `Cat_3` as well as age all the missing years and put `NA` as an value:

That is, in this example additional rows for the years 1991-1995 would be created for `Cat_3==y`and all combination of `Cat_1`, `Cat_2` and `Age` with `value=NA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
dt <- dt[
  CJ(Cat_3, Cat_1, Cat_2, Year, Age, unique = TRUE), 
  on = .(Cat_3, Cat_1, Cat_2, Year, Age)
  ]
```

Output for `dt[Cat_3 == "y",]`:

```
     Cat_1 Cat_2 Year Age Cat_3      value
  1:     A     u 1991  46     y         NA
  2:     A     u 1991  47     y         NA
  3:     A     u 1991  48     y         NA
  4:     A     u 1991  49     y         NA
  5:     A     u 1991  50     y         NA
 ---                                      
196:     B     v 2000  46     y 0.68144251
197:     B     v 2000  47     y 0.09916910
198:     B     v 2000  48     y 0.11890256
199:     B     v 2000  49     y 0.05043966
200:     B     v 2000  50     y 0.92925392
```